# This function gives different result if compiled with Visual-C++ or gnu g++

Tags: visual-c++, g++

The following function (extracted from a .cpp file) gives two different results (that is, the output buffer `int_image` is different) if executed on a PC with Visual Studio (cpu Intel i7 running Windows 7) or on my Android phone (P880). The two input buffers `im1` and `im2`, of type `int8` (a synonymous of `char`), are exactly the same (checked), as well as the parameters `w` and `h`. I can't understand why this is happening:

```
void  Compute(int8* im1,
              int8* im2,
              int w, 
              int h,
              int* int_image)
{
  int index = 0;
  int sum;

  for(int i = 0; i<h; i++)
  {
    // reset this column sum
    sum = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j<w; j++)
    {
      int pn;
      int8 v1, v2;
      v1 = im1[index];
      v2 = im2[index];
      pn = v1*v2;
      //pn = ((int)im1[index]) * ((int)im2[index]);
      sum += pn;
      if (i==0)
        int_image[index] = sum;
      else
        int_image[index] = int_image[index - w] + sum;

      index++;
    }
  }
}
```

Note.
The size of char images im1 and im2 can be such that an integer overflow can happen (but i think that this kind of situation is handled equally by the two compilers, but at this point i am not so sure).

Comment: The size of `int` can differ on different platforms so it's possible that your `int_image` is an array of 8-byte items on one platform and is an array of 4-byte items on another.

Comment: On both systems i have: sizeof(int)=4, sizeof(short int)=2, so this can't be the source of the error.

Comment: How is the output different? Simply by answering this question, you might see the answer: why does the function execute differently in different environments?

Answer (score 2):

Found the source of error. I defined `int8` as `char`, believing that by default it was a signed char. Instead, it is unsigned on gcc, while signed on Visual C++. I do not know what the standard says, but i suggest to all programmers out there to use explicitly `signed char` and `unsigned char` when defining your own macro for `int8` and `uint8`.
[Interesting discussion about this on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/char-is-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)